# Rendering a Kendo Menu from an Ext JS Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, extjs4.2

I'm combining ExtJS and Kendo UI - I realise this I'm off the reservation here ;)

I'm rendering a Kendo Menu onto an Ext JS (4.2.1) generated `Ext.form.Panel`

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/blackfrancis75/5e6Lgtaj/1/

The problem is that the drop-down items (on hover) get drawn only within the bounds of the Ext JS Panel.  Is there a way to have the drop down items show 'in front' of everything (I tried changing some of the classes `z-order`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `z-index` issue. It is parent `overflow: hidden` issue. If you have relatve container with `overflow: hidden` CSS property it will always work like that. Simple solution for kendo menu right now is to set all menu relative parents overflow to visible:

```
.x-panel,
.x-panel-body {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5e6Lgtaj/2/

But you must be beware that if you want to use it as scrollbars in them or actually hide overflow it will be a problem.

---

Other option would be append menu to body element, but you will face more problem then: like loose styling (cause it is moved from initial container with important classes), javascript functions to keep it in correct position and it will be more problems then it is worth.

This is first step how it could looks like:
http://jsfiddle.net/5e6Lgtaj/3/